# UI-Select2 persist changes with multiple selectable

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

I was wondering if there was an easy way to persist the selected data. Like the [events](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#events) for the jquery version of select2. But that doesn't seem to be supported in the angular version - sadly.

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-ui-select2 data-ng-model="data">
   ...
</select>
```

So far the only thing that seem to make sense is to watch the collection and apply some logic on the old and new value to detect if something was added or removed. But that just seem like something others might have done before :)

```
$scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   // logic to detect if something was added or removed
});
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore.js made it rather easy to detect added or removed items.

```
$scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   // logic to detect if something was added or removed
    if (newValue.length > oldValue.length) {
        // something was added
        var added = _.difference(_.pluck(newValue, 'id'), _.pluck(oldValue, 'id'));
        // do stuff
    } else if (newValue.length < oldValue.length) {
        // something was removed
        var removed = _.difference(_.pluck(oldValue, 'id'), _.pluck(newValue, 'id'));
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

But it's still a watch in the controller, which is not ideal.